# Certificate chain verification fails

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have three certificates in a chain:

- root.cer
- inter.cer
- leaf.cer

When I try to verify the chain by: **openssl verify -CAfile root.cer -untrusted inter.cer leaf.cer**
I get:

> C = GB, O = Jaguar Land Rover, OU = QA, CN = QA-JLR-ECUSigningCA 02
>
> error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate error leaf.cer:
>
> verification failed

I tried almost everything, but I always get this result. **QA-JLR-ECUSigningCA 02** is the **inter.cer**

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because either root.cert or inter.cer or both doesn't have 'CA:TRUE' in 'x509 Basic Constraints'.

You can read the both root and intermediate cert and check for the extension:

```
openssl x509 -in root.cer -noout -text
```

And, look for the following, it must be set for the verification to work.

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints:
        CA:TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Root has the "CA:TRUE", intermediate not. Does it mean I cannot verify the leaf certificate by the intermediate one?

Comment: 'openssl verify' will fail for sure. Not sure if you are using any other methods for verification.

Comment: Why should "openssl verify" fail? What other method should be used and not fail?

Comment: "openssl verify" requires all the certificates in the chain except leaf to have "CA:true" set. So, it will report an error if any intermediate or root cert in the chain doesn't have it. By other methods I meant, any custom implementation to verify where this parameter is not being checked.